# Google maps: "conversing" with forms

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a form that is meant to interact with a Google map.  At this point, I have one field for that will autocomplete with a business (using Google Places autocomplete).  What I need it to do now, though, is take that information in the autocomplete and re-draw the map to show the neighborhoods in that area (pointing out the 3 closest neighborhoods).

My question is, then, how do I take the information from the autocompleted field and "reuse" it to re-draw the map?  I've tried various ways but my second map doesn't ever render - let alone give me the 3 closest neighborhoods to an address form the autocompleted field!

Thanks in advance.  I've been searching high and low for this solution for weeks & need help getting it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `place_changed` event. You can then use the [`getPlace()`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Autocomplete) method to get a [`PlaceRestul`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#PlaceResult) object which will have an appropriate center point and possibly viewport.